# Error saving CiviCrm profile card in Drupal's user area

Tags: drupal, contacts, drupal-9

everybody. I have an error every time that an existent user saves the contact profile data in drupal, associated to civicrm fields. The Drupal's user data are updated correctly. The error is a bad one (the website encounter an error...), but it's enough to go back and everything is fine. It's recorded in PHP and Drupal watchdog. Could you please help me debugging it? I tried deleting some fields, but it doesn't work. It seems that the data are saved, anyway, but the error is confusing for the users.
The first three lines of the error:

[27-Feb-2023 00:42:48 Europe/Rome] TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given in /home/user/droopler/priv_files/civicrm/templates_c/it_IT/%%4D/4DC/4DC76B26%%body.tpl.php on line 15

#0 /home/user/droopler/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(1915): include()

#1 /home/user/droopler/priv_files/civicrm/templates_c/it_IT/%%0A/0AF/0AF6F87E%%Dynamic.tpl.php(43): Smarty->_smarty_include(Array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem related to php 8 that is fixed in civi 5.59. It will be released in about a week.

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2301

Comment: Thank you for your answer